# What is the By-Default value of a reference variable of a class which hasn't allocated any memory?

Tags: java

```
class D 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                D d;   // d is a reference variable of class D. what is its value?
                System.out.println(d);//An initializing error occurs.
            }
   }
```

Above given is a java program having A class name D which is referred to a reference variable d. I want to know what is the default value of d as of an uninitialized variable

Comment: Since your code will not compile, the variable never has *any* value.

Comment: @khelwood - Nicely put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gives an error because `d` is a local variable and all local variables must be initialized before they can be referenced. If `d` were to be an instance variable then the default value would be `null`. 
That said to fix the error in your code you have to fix a default value for `d`.

```
D d = null;
```

Comment: Please explain this with an errorless code.

Comment: Replace `D d;` in your code with `D d = null;`. My answer is pretty clear, that's just the rule in java.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.....!!